# packet travelling in layers

Tags: c, linux, networking, packet

I want to know how a network packet travels through different layers i.e. from physical layer to presentation layer in Linux systems. I want very detailed article or book on this topic with codes in C. I tried to Google it but unable to find. Any other type of guidance is welcomed. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[linux networking stack](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-networking-stack/) and 
[Linux network stack walkthrough](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/network/Linux_network_stack_walkthrough.html)

Google has even more if you want it. Google up "linux network stack"

Answer (score 2):

If you're really serious one of the standard references is [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201776316) by W. Richard Stevens. The first volume walks through the protocols from Ethernet up to TCP and a few application layer protocols. This show how the bits are supposed are moved around and interpreted. Volume 2 goes through a BSD implementation. If you want an in-depth understanding Stevens is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the exact thing what I wanted.